# Random variable as tensor product of its components

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra

Consider a finite random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ on a probability space $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega}, P)$. Let $H_{\Omega}$ and $H_E$ be two Hilbert spaces with basis states $ \{| \omega \rangle\}{\omega \in \Omega}$ and $\{| x \rangle\}{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}$ respectively. We say that a unitary $B_X$ acting on $H_{\Omega} \otimes H_E$ is a binary oracle for $X$ if
$$B_X: | \omega \rangle | 0 \rangle \rightarrow | \omega \rangle | X(\omega) \rangle$$
for all $\omega \in \Omega$, assuming $|  0 \rangle \in E$.
If I treat $$|X(\omega)\rangle = |X(\omega)_1\rangle \otimes |X(\omega)_2\rangle \otimes \ldots \otimes |X(\omega)_d\rangle, $$ then I am lacking the interpretation of this. So if each component is in $\mathbb{R}$, I would only have 1 basis state? So I could describe each component with 1 qubit having only 1 parameter. Does this make sense?

Comment: What is $E$? Note that this construction would come with a clear interpretation if $E$ were the range of $X$, i.e. $X:\Omega\to E$ since then $|X(\omega)\rangle$ is just the basis state in $H_E$ associated with $X(\omega)$. If $E=\mathbb{R}^d$ then $H_E$ has uncountable basis. For a concrete picture of such a Hilbert space one could imagine an infinite chain of qubits, one for each integer. The computational basis states of a certain proper subspace of this space can be thought of as encoding real numbers.

Comment: Sorry $E$ should be $\mathbb{R}^d$. So I would have an infinite set of basis states for each component $X(\omega)_i$ consisting of every integer of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What proper subspace can be chosen to encode the real number. Can it be finite to be computable?

Comment: @AdamZalcman: Can you answer that maybe?